How can I create user and user associated token account (ATA) in rust test case?
I am currently creating a mint address , user and its ata address using spl library in contrast with solana-sdk and solana-client.
The code involves airdrops too to fund wallet (payer) before the ata is created.
Consider create_user_and_ata function It is cauing below error

error: linking with cc failed: exit status: 1
Below is the code

 use solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
 use solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey;
 use solana_sdk::signature::{Keypair, Signer};
 use solana_sdk::transaction::Transaction;
 use solana_sdk::system_instruction;
 use spl_associated_token_account::get_associated_token_address;
 use spl_token::instruction as token_instruction;
 use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

 #[tokio::main]
 async fn main() {
// Initialize RpcClient
let client = RpcClient::new("http://localhost:8899");

// Create wallet (payer) and user keypairs
let wallet = Keypair::new();
let user = Keypair::new();

// Airdrop some SOL to the wallet to pay for transaction fees
let airdrop_signature = client.request_airdrop(&wallet.pubkey(), 10_000_000_000).unwrap();
client.confirm_transaction(&airdrop_signature).unwrap();

// Create a mint and associated token account (ATA) for the user
let mint_pubkey = create_mint(&client, &wallet, 6).await;
let (user_keypair, user_ata) = create_user_and_ata(&client, &wallet, mint_pubkey).await;

// Mint some tokens to the user's ATA
fund_ata(&client, &wallet, mint_pubkey, user_ata, 6).await;

// Get the balance of the user's ATA
let balance = get_token_balance(&client, user_ata).await;
println!("User's token balance: {}", balance);

}
// Function to create a new mint
async fn create_mint(
client: &RpcClient,
payer: &Keypair,
decimals: u8,
) -> Pubkey {
let mint = Keypair::new();
let lamports = client
    .get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(spl_token::state::Mint::LEN)
    .unwrap();

let transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[
        system_instruction::create_account(
            &payer.pubkey(),
            &mint.pubkey(),
            lamports,
            spl_token::state::Mint::LEN as u64,
            &spl_token::ID,
        ),
        token_instruction::initialize_mint(
            &spl_token::ID,
            &mint.pubkey(),
            &payer.pubkey(),
            None,
            decimals,
        )
        .unwrap(),
    ],
    Some(&payer.pubkey()),
    &[payer, &mint],
    client.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap(),
  );

client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&transaction).unwrap();
mint.pubkey()
 }

// Function to create a user and associated token account (ATA)
async fn create_user_and_ata(
client: &RpcClient,
payer: &Keypair,
mint: Pubkey,
) -> (Keypair, Pubkey) {
let user = Keypair::new();

let airdrop_signature = client.request_airdrop(&user.pubkey(), 10 * 
solana_sdk::native_token::LAMPORTS_PER_SOL).unwrap();
client.confirm_transaction(&airdrop_signature).unwrap();

sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;

let ata = get_associated_token_address(&user.pubkey(), &mint);
let transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[spl_associated_token_account::create_associated_token_account(
        &payer.pubkey(),
        &user.pubkey(),
        &mint,
    )],
    Some(&payer.pubkey()),
    &[payer],
    client.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap(),
);

client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&transaction).unwrap();

(user, ata)
}

// Function to fund the ATA
 async fn fund_ata(
 client: &RpcClient,
 payer: &Keypair,
 mint: Pubkey,
 user_ata: Pubkey,
 decimals: u8,
 ) {
let transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[
        token_instruction::mint_to(
            &spl_token::ID,
            &mint,
            &user_ata,
            &payer.pubkey(),
            &[],
            2000 * 10u64.pow(decimals as u32),
        )
        .unwrap(),
    ],
    Some(&payer.pubkey()),
    &[payer],
    client.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap(),
   );

   client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&transaction).unwrap();
  }

// Function to get the token balance
    async fn get_token_balance(
  client: &RpcClient,
  token_account: Pubkey,
    ) -> u64 {
 let account = client.get_account(&token_account).unwrap();
let token_account = spl_token::state::Account::unpack(&account.data).unwrap();
token_account.amount
}


The error of error: linking with cc failed: exit status: 1 points to some other issue than your code. Can you post the full error output?

asset me that how can I create atas using rust
